# How can I use Morphia to map a non-annotated pojo?

Tags: java, inheritance, morphia

A class exists that I have no control over:

```
public class MyPerson {
  private String name;
  private int elevation;

  // getters and setters
}
```

I want to persist this person into Mongo, but I cannot alter this class definition with `@Entity` and other annotations.

I'd like the document in Mongo to look something akin to:

```
{ name : "You", elevation : 65 }
```

What's the best way to approach this? Converter? Extended class? Containing class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just embed it in one you control, and can put the @Id on.

Answer (score 0):

Must work:

```
morhpia.map(MyPerson.class);
Datastore ds = morhpia.createDatastore(mongo, "my_database");
MyPerson pe = new MyPerson();
pe.setName("cmonkey");
ds.save(pe);
```

**BUT**
You must add @Id field in the POJO. Its is required by Morphia.

Comment: Alas, as I am unable to add the `@Id` annotation and field directly, this may not be a solution for me.

Comment: You can try to use Reflection to add this Annotation. Or better - use wrapper class with  @Id field

Comment: I think if you extend the class, then mark the subclass as an `@Entity` and add the `@Id` field it should persist the fields from the super-class. The MyPerson class definitely isn't final - then you're stuck.